# Integration over a non-trivial surface

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

I am currently working on a problem involving Young´s double slit interference experiment. What I want to do is to evaluate a integral over a surface that looks something like this:
[image]

where the integral is to be taken over the red surface only, and the integrand depends on the radius of the circle. What would be the best way to do this numerically in matlab?

Comment: Could you please give some more details? What's the integrand? What are the angles describing the circular segments you've drawn there? What's the radius of the circle?

Comment: Separate into two separate integrals for the two regions, then define the circle in terms of $x$.